# how to get list of folders of phone's sdcard(External Memory Card) in phonegap

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

i was using phonegap's file to list all the folders inside the phone using  this code.

```
      document.addEventListener("deviceready", makeFileSystemReady, true);
      var globalFileSystem;
      function makeFileSystemReady(){
      window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, onFileSystemSuccess, onFileSystemError);
      }


    function onFileSystemSuccess(fs){
    globalFileSystem=fs; //Initialized the global file system.
     }


    function onFileSystemError(){
    console.log("Unable to load the file System Plugin");
    }

   function chooseFromGallery(){
   var dirReader = globalFileSystem.root.createReader();
   dirReader.readEntries(galleryFiles,galleryFilesErrors);
   }

    function galleryFiles(entries){
    var s = "<p style='color:white'>";
    console.log(globalFileSystem.root);
    for(var i=0,len=entries.length; i<len; i++) {
    //entry objects include: isFile, isDirectory, name, fullPath
    s+= entries[i].fullPath;
    if (entries[i].isFile) {
    s += " [F]";
    }
    else {
    s += " [D]";
    }
    s += "<br/>";

    }
    s+="<p/>";

document.getElementById('videoArea').innerHTML=s;
}

 function galleryFilesErrors(){
  alert("Unable to use the file system !");
  }
```

This code is working fine, but the problem here is, how can i get the list of folders inside my SD Card or External Storage of my Phone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation for the cordoba-plugin-file has the identifiers for the different locations.

https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file

In this case you want to use cordova.file.externalRootDirectory which will resolve to the right directory entry when you pass it to window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL().